# Windows phone Horizontal Listbox image center-lock

Tags: xaml, listbox, windows-phone, android-viewpager

I have a `ListBox` with images as items, I need each image to take the full width of the screen, and to be center-locked (like `ViewPager` in android)

this is what I have so far:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Zones[0].listBannieres}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding banniere}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

thank you.

**SOLVED**

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Zone 1"  Margin="0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                        <phone:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding Zones[0].listBannieres}">
                            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate />
                            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                            <phone:Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="phone:PivotItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </phone:Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding banniere}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                        </phone:Pivot>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
```

Comment: And how would you perform the navigation?

Comment: by sliding the listbox

Comment: Use `Pivot` then instead of `ListBox` because you will have a hard time making it work.

Comment: I've just a banner in the bottom of the page, I've tried using Pivot but that made the whole page scrollable

Comment: You can place Pivot wherever you want on the page and you can change its size. Just don't set headers nor title.

Comment: @Jawad i think set width of image is trick for you.  <Image Source="{Binding banniere}" Width="440" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Pivot as suggested in the comments or a Panorama control, if you place those inside another control, you can have them visible at the bottom only. Here is an example with pivot:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <phone:Pivot Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Margin="0">
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate></DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <phone:Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="phone:PivotItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>

        <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Here only the bottom part is scrolled to as you wanted. It will also "snap" to the images when scrolling, which I also think the Android viewpager does. :)

If you instead change Pivot to Panorama and PivotItem to PanoramaItem you can get another nice result, where you see a small part of the next image. Here is an image of the result:

[image]

Edit: To remove the margin and headers, make sure you set the HeaderTemplate to an empty one and the Margin on PivotItem to 0. See the updated code above.

Comment: I updated the answer to remove margin and header when using ItemsSource.